# ValueError on concatenation - Shape of passed values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to concatenate two dataframes

```
df_concat = pd.concat([df_a, df_a ], axis=1)
```

I get the following error

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (8761, 2), indices imply (8760, 2)
```

I've pulled the two sets of data into csv and confirmed they have the same number of rows (including headers).

There is one duplicate in the index column of df_a so this might be the problem. If so, how can I ignore or remove the duplicate index point?

Comment: Welcome to So. Please share data for the two dataframes so we may have something to 1. Reproduce the error 2. Give you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Without any data to test a solution. You could try to do this by

```
df_etr_h_hor.reset_index(drop=True.merge(df_global_h.reset_index(drop=True))
```